# Change side on \path connection in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make the connection as shown in the figure attached? I have a line commented on my code which I tried but is not working.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
    auto,
    decision/.style = { diamond, draw=black, thick, fill=gray!30, text width=5em, text centered, inner sep=1pt },
    block/.style    = { rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white, text width=10em, text centered, minimum height=2em },
    line/.style     = { draw, thick, ->, shorten >=1pt },
  ]
  % Define nodes in a matrix
  \matrix [column sep=5mm, row sep=6mm] {
                    & \node [block] (H) {Calculate H};                              & \\
                    & \node [block] (eq3) {Solve Eq.3};                             & \\
                    & \node [decision] (y) {$y\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)=h$};         & \\
                    & \node [block] (Dy) {Update $y(x)$};                           & \\
                    & \node [block] (Hnew) {Calculate H};                           & \\
                    & \node [decision] (HH) {H changed?};                           & \\
                    & \node [text centered] (out) {Results};                        & \\
  };
  % connect all nodes defined above
  \begin{scope} [every path/.style=line]
    \path (H)       --      (eq3);
    \path (eq3)     --      (y);
    \path (HH)      --++    (-3,0) node [near start] {yes} |- (eq3);
    \path (y)       --      node [near start] {no} (Dy);
%    \path (y)      --      (3,0) node [near start] {yes} -| (Hnew); THIS WAS MY TRY!!! NOT WORKING
    \path (Dy)      --      (Hnew);
    \path (Hnew)    --      (HH);
    \path (HH)      --      node [near start] {no} (out);
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change line

```
%    \path (y) -- (3,0) node [near start] {yes} -| (Hnew); THIS NOT WORKING
```

in your *mwe* to

```
 \path (y.east)  node [above right] {yes} -- + (2,0) |- (Hnew);
```

you will obtain:

[image]

however, since flowchart is relative simple, its code can be simplified by use of `chains` instead of `matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
  node distance = 5mm and 1mm,
    start chain = A going below,
decision/.style = { diamond, aspect=1.5, draw=black, thick, fill=gray!30,
                    text width=5em, align=center, inner sep=1pt,
                    on chain=A, join=by line},
   block/.style = { rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
                    text width=10em, align=center,  minimum height=2em,
                    on chain=A, join=by line},
    line/.style = { draw, thick, ->, shorten >=1pt },
                    ]
  % Define nodes in a matrix
\node [block]       {Calculate H};                      % A-1
\node [block]       {Solve Eq.3};                       % A-2
\node [decision]    {$y\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)=h$};    % A-3
\node [block]       {Update $y(x)$};                    % A-4
\node [block]       {Calculate H};                      % A-5
\node [decision]    {H changed?};                       % A-6
% non join nodes' connections
\draw[line] (A-6.west) node [above  left] {yes} -- + (-2,0) |- (A-2);
\draw[line] (A-3.east) node [above right] {yes} -- + ( 2,0) |- (A-5);
% edge labels
\node[below right] at (A-3.south) {no};
\draw[line] (A-6.south)  -- ++  (0,-0.6) node [below] {Results};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zarko.
It's my very first time making this kind of diagrams in Latex and I just found an example which I changed to adapt to my needs. I was almost sure there were way simpler methods to do it. Thanks again for the help and the hints.

Comment: @CarlosCordeiro, you are welcome! happy tex-ing!